# Using Google App Engine DEV behind Proxy Server

Tags: google-app-engine

I am using Google App Engine behind a proxy server using the Python language. All of the function calls using urlfetch.fetch(url) are failing.

When I run the same code on a machine without a proxy server, it works.

Anyone has an idea how to solve this?

Note: The code upload to prod App Engine does not work also when I'm behind the proxy server.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a known issue. There's a [bug filed on it](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=544); that page also details some workarounds.